# Android: MediaRecorder start failed : -16

Tags: android

I've been trying to implement a video camera. But it never worked because of this mysterious error (-16) on recorder.start().

Here is my code:

```
private void initRecorder(int width, int height) {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
        params.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);

        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        File mediaFile = null;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            mediaFile = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Towncare/Temp/vid_temp.3gpp");
            if (!mediaFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    mediaFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    mediaFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        ;
        recorder.setOutputFile(android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Towncare/Temp/vid_temp.3gpp");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000);
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder.getSurface());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Here is the log:

> 04-20 18:27:26.178: I/MediaRecorderJNI(13225): prepare: surface=0x257468 (identity=1459)
>   04-20 18:27:27.548: E/MediaRecorder(13225): start failed: -16
>   04-20 18:27:27.558: D/AndroidRuntime(13225): Shutting down VM
>   04-20 18:27:27.558: W/dalvikvm(13225): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at com.packagename.app.FullCameraActivity$3.onClick(FullCameraActivity.java:84)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9116)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
>   04-20 18:27:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I know there are some duplicates but none of them has the answers that worked for me. Please help me out here. Thanks in Advance

Comment: where do you use `recorder.start()` ? I couldn't find from your code

Comment: @Ulugbek Komilovich, as the log above suggests:`.onClick(FullCameraActivity.java:84`, the `recorder.start()` is called inside of `onClick` listener of a button. However, I assume you are right. Because the full code, if possible, should be provided here.

Comment: can't provide full code, sorry :(. but ya, u r right, its inside onclick